# HTML email, remove spacing between tr tags?

Tags: html, css, email

I have tried adding cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" . Does not fix the issue in email clients.

Here is a image of the spacing in gmail:

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Openx Webinar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
    <table align="center" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" >
        <!-- Header -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td id="header" width="600" valign="top" align="left"><img src="http://openx.dev.limusdesign.com/emails/webinar/images/header.png" alt="OpenX Webinar Series"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="banner" width="600" valign="top" align="left"><img src="http://openx.dev.limusdesign.com/emails/webinar/images/banner.png" alt="Banner Image"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="600" height="20" valign="top" align="left"></td> 
            </tr>   
        </thead>
         </table>
     </div>
    </body>

<html>
```

Any advice on how I can fix this? NOTE: this is for HTML email.

UPDATED HEADER CODE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Openx Webinar</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
    <table align="center" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" >
        <!-- Header -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td id="header" width="600" valign="top" align="left">
                    <img src="http://openx.dev.limusdesign.com/emails/webinar/images/header.png" alt="OpenX Webinar Series" height="65" style="display:block">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="banner" width="600" valign="top" align="left">
                    <img src="http://openx.dev.limusdesign.com/emails/webinar/images/banner.png" alt="Banner Image" height="180" style="display:block">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="600" height="20" valign="top" align="left"></td> 
            </tr>   
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not have a closing table or proper closing html tag. Fix that first.

Comment: and don't close the `<div>`tag

Comment: Added closing table and div tag. Still didn't fix it..

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ - Validate your code first. Also, my guess is border-collapse, but I'll test it out once your code is valid.

Comment: Code is valid according to w3 validator...

Comment: The code you posted is **not** valid.

Comment: @Conexion its not the full HTML email code. I made some minor adjustments to the code and validated it in w3 validator and it passed the test there.

Comment: `margins` don't work in all email clients, it's best to stick with padding.

Comment: I'm very curious how you have two `<html>` elements with it still validating. If your code is now valid, could you update the original code you posted since that won't affect the issue, and it might help others who see this in the future?

Comment: I cannot post my full code due to client related concerns but I have updated my post with just the header code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding a `style="display:block"` to images.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Openx Webinar</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="padding:0;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
    <table align="center" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" >
      <tr>
        <td id="header" width="600" valign="top" align="left" style="padding:0px;outline:none;border:none;">
        <img src="http://openx.dev.limusdesign.com/emails/webinar/images/header.png" alt="OpenX Webinar Series" style="padding:0px;outline:none;border:none;"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="banner" width="600" valign="top" align="left" style="padding:0px;outline:none;border:none;">
        <img src="http://openx.dev.limusdesign.com/emails/webinar/images/banner.png" alt="Banner Image" style="padding:0px;outline:none;border:none;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="600" height="20" valign="top" align="left"></td> 
      </tr>   
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the space between the tr tags simply add border-collapse: collapse; to your table tag. Like for a table within an email you can add it as:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change display option for `<td></td>` that contains the first image:

```
thead tr:first-child td
{
  display: block;
  height:65px;
}
```

or for the img itself

```
thead tr:first-child td img
{
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Start by putting your table in another table that has the width set to 100%.
2. interior table set to 600 and is center holds all contents
3. no longer will you need to put width or align on every td. That is bloating your email.
4. block works. As does valign top.
5. Get better results!
6. Sorry, Get rid of Div. Tables are just that. s
7. Don't use classes.
8. Cellpadding and Cellspacing are Dynamite and a torch. You're going to blow stuff up.